# Inline Edit on Custom Metadata

Tags: visualforce, inlineeditsupport, custom-metadata

Is it possible to use inline edit feature with Custom Metadata? In most cases custom mdt acts like sObjects, however I cannot make it work and I can't find any related docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't currently possible.